# daterangepicker not folding open with bootstrap in Laravel 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, laravel, bootstrap-4

I've been working on a reporting engine, have all the graphs working using Ajax and jquery to update the page. I wanted to add a date range picker and went to [Date Range Picker Examples](https://www.daterangepicker.com/)

I am able to get it so it has the icon and the dates populate when the page loads.  But when I click on the field it doesn't open to giving the option to select.  I took the sample code and was able to get it to work with only it on the page. In the console, I don't see any errors.  I'm just getting into jquery etc so I'm perplexed at why this isn't working.

HTML Content

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-auto">
            <h1>Report for {{ $labels['Company'] }}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 float-right">
    <div id="reportrange" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
        <span></span> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </div>
    </div>
        <div class=" justify-content-around bg-white">


            <div class="d-flex justify-content-around bg-white">
            <div class="card text-center border-0">
                <div class="card-body">
                     <div class="test rounded-circle font-weight-bolder col-xs" id="impressions"></div>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted pt-2 align-content-center">Impressions</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card text-center border-0">
                <div class="card-body ">
                    <div class="test rounded-circle font-weight-bolder col-xs" id="clicks"></div>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted pt-2 align-content-center">Clicks</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card text-center border-0">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="test rounded-circle font-weight-bolder col-xs" id="cpm"></div>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted pt-2 align-content-center">eCPM</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card text-center border-0">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="test rounded-circle font-weight-bolder col-xs" id="cost"></div>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted pt-2 align-content-center">Cost</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card text-center border-0">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="test rounded-circle font-weight-bolder col-xs" id="cpc"></div>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted pt-2 align-content-center">CPC</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card text-center border-0">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="test rounded-circle font-weight-bolder col-xs" id="ctr"></div>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted pt-2 align-content-center">CTR</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <canvas id="myAreaChart" width="100%" height="30"></canvas>
    </div>

        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Dashboard</div>

                    <div class="card-body">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Script section

```
 <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" ></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {


        var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
        var end = moment();

        function cb(start, end) {
            $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
        }

        $(".rangeArea").load("reportRange", function() {
            $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({

            startDate: start,
            endDate: end,
            ranges: {
                'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
                'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
            }
        }, cb);
        })
        cb(start, end);
});

        ( function ( $ ) {

            var charts = {
                init: function () {
                    // -- Set new default font family and font color to mimic Bootstrap's default styling
                    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = '-apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif';
                    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#292b2c';

                    this.ajaxGetPostMonthlyData();

                },

                ajaxGetPostMonthlyData: function () {
                    var urlPath =  'http://' + window.location.hostname + ':8000/admin/comp/get-post-chart-data/'+{{$labels['orgid']}};
                    var request = $.ajax( {
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: urlPath
                    } );

                    request.done( function ( response ) {

                        $("#ctr").html(response.totals.ctr);
                        $("#cpc").html(response.totals.cpc);
                        $("#cost").html(response.totals.cost);
                        $("#cpm").html(response.totals.cpm);
                        $("#clicks").html(response.totals.clicks);
                        $("#impressions").html(response.totals.impressions);

                        charts.createCompletedJobsChart( response );
                    });
                },

                /**
                 * Created the Completed Jobs Chart
                 */

                createCompletedJobsChart: function ( response ) {
                    console.log(response);
                    var days = new Array();
                    var clicks = new Array();
                    var impressions = new Array();
                    $.each(response.totalByDate, function (index, value){

                      days.push(value['days']);
                      clicks.push(value['clicks']);
                      impressions.push(value['impressions']);

                    });
                    var daysFiltered = days.filter(e => e != null);
                    var clicksFiltered = clicks.filter(e => e != null);
                    var impressionsFiltered = impressions.filter(e => e != null);
                    console.log(impressions);
                    var data = {
                        labels: daysFiltered,
                        datasets: [{
                            fill: false,
                            type: 'bar',
                            label: 'Impressions',
                            pointHoverRadius: 5,
                            pointHitRadius: 5,
                            lineTension: 0,
                            yAxisID: 'impressionID',
                            data: impressionsFiltered,
                            borderColor: "#993333",
                            // borderDash: [5, 5],
                            backgroundColor: "#993333",
                            pointBackgroundColor: "#993333",
                            pointBorderColor: "#993333",
                            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#993333",
                            pointHoverBorderColor: "#993333",
                            order:2
                        }, {
                            fill: false,
                            type: 'line',
                            pointHoverRadius: 5,
                            pointHitRadius: 5,
                            lineTension: 0,
                            yAxisID: 'clicksID',
                            label: 'Clicks',
                            data: clicksFiltered,
                            borderColor: "#55bae7",
                           // borderDash: [5, 5],
                            backgroundColor: "#55bae7",
                            pointBackgroundColor: "#55bae7",
                            pointBorderColor: "#55bae7",
                            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#55bae7",
                            pointHoverBorderColor: "#e755ba",
                            order: 1
                        }]
                    };
                    var option = {
                        maintainAspectRatio: true,
                        responsive: true,
                        bezierCurveTension: 0,
                        scales: {
                            xAxes: [{
                                display: true,
                                ticks: {
                                    maxTicksLimit: 3,
                                    fontSize: 10
                                }
                            }],
                            yAxes: [{
                                position: 'left',
                                'id': 'impressionID',
                                display: true,
                                ticks: {
                                    steps: 100,
                                    stepValue: 5,
                                    max: 800,
                                    callback: (label, index, labels) => {
                                        return label ;
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                position: 'right',
                                'id': 'clicksID',

                                display: true,
                                ticks: {
                                    steps: 1,
                                    stepValue: 1,
                                    precision: 0,
                                    max: 5,
                                    callback: (label, index, labels) => {
                                        return label ;
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            ]
                        }
                    };
                    var ctx = document.getElementById("myAreaChart");
                    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                        type: 'line',
                        data: data,
                        options: option

                    });
                }
            };

            charts.init();

        } )( jQuery );
    </script>
```

Comment: can you please add the fiddle of above code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1Lxva0ge/#&togetherjs=i4tz9vOnDR

Comment: And I just noticed on my server that the admin pulldown that is vanilla laravel isn't working either. So something for clicking to open seems amiss :|